# Exercise: Web Crawler - print not working

Tags: go

> I'm a golang newbie and currently working on [Exercise: Web Crawler](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10).

I simply put the keyword 'go' before every place where func Crawl is invoked and hope it can be parallelized, but `fmt.Printf` doesn't work and prints nothing. Nothing other is changed on the original code besides this one. Would someone like to give me a hand?

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
    // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
    // This implementation doesn't do either:
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    go Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution)

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.

Therefore you have to explicitly wait for the other goroutine to end in `main()` function.

One way is simply add `time.Sleep()` at the end of `main()` function until you think that the other goroutine ends (e.g. maybe 1 second in this case).

Cleaner way is using [sync.WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) as follows:

```
func Crawl(wg *sync.WaitGroup, url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    defer wg.Done()
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        go Crawl(wg, u, depth-1, fetcher)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    // first call does not need to be goroutine since its subroutine is goroutine.
    Crawl(wg, "https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
    //time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

This code stores counter in `WaitGroup`, increment it using `wg.Add()`, decrement using `wg.Done()` and waits until it goes zero using `wg.Wait()`.

Confirm it in go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/WqQBqe6iFLp

Comment: Seems like Java's CountDownLatch. So goroutines works only if  the main process is running?

Comment: @BingZhao Edited the answer, please confirm.